# How to use Google Apps Script into my Website on button click?

Tags: asp.net, google-apps-script

I have an Google apps script and I want to call this Google apps script on my web page?How can I achieve this?This is my Google apps Script code for creating a google doc on my drive.

```
function createAndSendDocument() {   
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('Hello World');  
  doc.appendParagraph('This document was created by my first Google Apps Script.');
  doc.saveAndClose(); 
  var url = doc.getUrl();  
  var emailAddress = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();  
  GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,
                     'Hello '+ url);
}
```

and I want to call this function when I click on a button on my web page.But I don't know how to call this function on my button click.And one more thing I also save this script and change this version number and deploy as a web app and get the URL of this Google apps Script.

**UPDATE:** (added incorrectly in an answer)
Actually i am using this line like this.

```
btnClick.addEventListener("click", function () {
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "GoogleFunction", "createAndSendDocument()", true);
```

}
So please now tell me what's wrong in that?When i run my application then it's show me an error like "The Page is not defined".

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.Actually I want to use Google Apps Script into my web page just like we are using javascript file into a web page.but i don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Look also at [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_gadgets?hl=fr-FR) and also [this one](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service?hl=fr-FR), everything is clearly explained .

Answer (score 0):

you can add the div and the code in your page as you needed. also you need to add the javascript codes inside your head if it exists.

Comment: "inside your head if it exists" :|. I think he got it but still sounds a bit weird

Comment: <head> <script> do the scripts if exists... </script></head>

Comment: I know, just sounded a bit funny

Answer (score 0):

hi you can use this code on button click after adding a script manager in the form

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"GoogleFunction","createAndSendDocument()",true);
```